# Merge columns where cells have same values, excluding "0"s

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, merge

I've seen many questions on merging, but nothing that I can manipulate (in my entry-level abilities) to answer this particular question and would be forever be grateful for your expertise and help!!!

I am looking to merge different groups of cells with the same values for particular ranges.

Below is an example of inputs and the desired outcome. I have the file formatted so that the "0"s and "no"s don't show, however the actual descriptions (substituted with like 50% off) are quite long and cannot be viewed in a single cell, hence the need for merge cells to better display information. There are also multiple stores with new stores being added weekly, thus I would like to avoid merging cells manually.

Input

```
Month                   January February    March     April       May
Store 1 Campaign Period   no      yes       yes       yes         no
Campaign Details          0       50% off   50% off   50% off     0
Store 2 Campaign Period   no      no        no        yes        yes
Campaign Details          0       0         0    spring fling   spring fling
```

Desired Output

```
Month                   January February    March   April     May
Store 1 Campaign Period   no     yes         yes    yes       no
Campaign Details          0            50% off                0
Store 2 Campaign Period   no     no          no     yes       yes
Campaign Details          0      0            0     spring fling
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. In order to get help, you need to show your personal attempt at writing the macro. Basically, you will span the cells in the table and whenever a set of neighbor cells (on the same row, i guess) have the same "description text", merge them. Start this or post your current code if you already did, and we will be happy to help you finalize it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! When I enter the below code I receive an error of "Out of Memory"

Comment: Sorry here it is: Sub sbMergeColumns()

For i = 16 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



If Range("di:Bdi") <> "0" Or Range("di:Bdi") <> "" Then GoTo 16
16
Range("di:Bdi").Merge (True)

Next

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.  The data is assumed to be in "Sheet1".  It will merge cells in rows that are labeled with "Campaign Details" in Column 'A'. The merge is performed on adjacent row cells that have the same value - at least two adjacent cells with the same value will be merged.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeSameDetails()
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  With sht
    Dim lastrow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, cnt As Integer
    Dim val As Variant
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
      If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Campaign Details" Then
        cnt = 1
        val = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        For j = 3 To 7
          If val = .Cells(i, j).Value Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
          Else
            If cnt >= 2 And val <> "0" Then
              .Range(Cells(i, j - cnt), Cells(i, j - 1)).Merge
              .Cells(i, j - cnt).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End If
            cnt = 1
            val = .Cells(i, j).Value
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  End With

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've tried editing this code for "Campaign Details" to begin in column "C" and adjust for the j range to be from "D:BD" however receive the error " Subscript out of range". I then edited my excel sheet so that "Campaign Details" was in column "A" but still received the same error. Can you please help?

Comment: Ahhhhhh nevermind! I played around with it a bit and adjusted the column settings and it worked! THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!